# Function that at $L_{2}$ but not in $L_{1}$ and also not in $L_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

as part of my effort to learn some functional analysis I'm trying to find an example to a function that is in $L^{2}$ $[0,\infty)$ but not in $L^{1}$ $[0,\infty)$ and also not in $L^{\infty}$ $[0,\infty)$.

I Thought of the following function: $\cfrac{1}{(t-1)}$ but this also not in $L_{2}$.

Would appreciate some help
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $f,g \geq 0$, $f \in L^{2}\setminus L^{1}$ and $g \in L^{2}\setminus L^{\infty}$ then  $f+g$ would be such a  function.

Comment: thanks, can you refer to place to find the proof for that? also would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: Proof of what? It is obvious that $f+g$ cannot be in $L^{1}$ unless $f$ and $g$ are both in $L^{1}$  because they are positive functions. Similarly for $L^{\infty}$

Comment: If you are unable to find $f$ and $g$ I will be glad to give an example.

Comment: Im trying to think of $f$ and $g$ functions that satisfy your answer. If ill get stuck ill ask. Thank you!!!

Comment: so for $f$ I think (correct me if im wrong) that a function $\cfrac{1}{t}\,(1,\infty)$ and $f=0\,[0,1]$ will satisfy that its in $L^{2}$ but not in $L^{1}$. but I can't seem to think of a function $g$

Comment: You need a square-integrable singularity.

Comment: ok I think I found a function $g$ that satisfy, $t^{-\cfrac{1}{4}}\,[0,1]$ and $0\,(1,\infty)$. am I right with the functions I suggested here and in the other comment?

Comment: @chemist Both are correct and they are in fact the examples I had in mind!.